# Javascript with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a javascript code usign regex such that it validate license plate. I want a pater for my license plate is 6-8 digit that is not more than 8 and not less than 6 it would be 6 or 7 or 8. But digit should be alphanumeric so I tried function as.

```
<!----------LICENSE PLATE---------->
var strFilter = /^[A-Za-z0-9]$/;
var obj = document.getElementById("licenseplate");

if ((!strFilter.test(obj)) || (obj.length < 6) || (obj.length > 8)){
    alert("Please enter valid 6-8 digit license plate.");
    obj.focus();
    obj.style.background = "#DFE32D";
    obj.value = "";
    return false;
}
```

It gives me error on all condition that if all are numeric or all are alphabetic or are combination of both.

Comment: What on earth is an HTML comment doing in JavaScript code?!

Comment: As I was following patter on my pages so I used it... Well Its inpage validation that may be second reason for using HTML comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z]{6,8}$/
```

Comment: 12222222, 122AAA22,5566AVA or anything else Its giving me error.

Comment: try document.getElementById("licenseplate").value

Answer (score 1):

obj.length is not right... obj, as returned by `document.getElementById()` is a DOM node, not a String. Assuming `licenseplate` is a form field:

```
var strFilter = /^[0-9A-Za-z]{6,8}$/;
var obj = document.getElementById("licenseplate");
if (!strFilter.test(obj.value)) {
    alert("Please enter valid 6-8 digit license plate.");
    obj.focus();
    obj.style.background = "#DFE32D";
    obj.value = "";
    return false;
}
```

This works.